# Supresss the 'no such file or directory' message from 'find'

Tags: linux, find

I'm trying to find a directory with this command:

```
find /users/dan/ -name 'Prams' -type d
```

I see a huge amount of 'No such file or directory' output. Is there a way to make [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find) shut up if it doesn't find anything?

Comment: this worked for me:    find /users/dan/ -name 'Prams' -type d | tee log

Comment: the pipe without ampersand only outputs std output. If it was |& log, it will print those errors as well.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
find /users/dan/ -name 'Prams' -type d 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: it says: find:paths must precede expression. I am running linux 2.6.9-67.0.7

Comment: which flavor: can you run `uname -a`

Comment: Linux machine-3 2.6.9-67.0.7.ELsmp #1 SMP Wed Feb 27 04:47:23 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: this worked for me: find /users/dan/ -name 'Prams' -type d | tee log

Comment: interesting, this didn't work for me

Comment: I am at a work machine. could be a lot of custom tools/distros, so i am not surprised

Comment: probably, I am using Ubuntu which is probably different from yours

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress the STDERR output:

```
find /users/dan/ -name 'Prams' -type d 2> /dev/null
```

Or you can use `find` to show all directories and filter its output with `grep`:

```
find /users/dan -type d | grep "Prams"
```

The `find` command won't print "no such file or directory" if the search path (`/users/dan`, in this case) exists, even if there are no matches.  Are you sure this directory exists?

Answer (score 0):

His syntax is correct if indeed `/users/dan/ <` exists in the first place!

There should be no 'No such file or directory' outputs in the first place.

```
find $HOME -name 'Prams' -type d
```